# aws configure を、 csv から読み取って実行するようなスクリプトはありますか?

Tags: aws, aws-cli

いくつもの aws の鍵を管理していると、それを aws configure する機会が多くなります。

やることは決まりきっていて、

1. csv ダウンロード
2. その内容にしたがって aws configure
3. その際に、プロファイルも指定する

これは、特に aws キーのセキュリティ的な性質を考えれば、画面に一時的にでも表示されてほしくないので、 csv ファイル(とオプショナルでプロファイル名)を引数にとって、あとは自動で設定してくれるコマンドがほしいと思いました。

#### 質問

csv を引数にとって aws configure してくれるようなスクリプトないしツールはありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まさにそのような動作をする `aws configure import` を追加する [PR](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/3813) が出ていますが、放置気味ですね。

ワンライナーだとこうでしょうか。

```
sed -ne '$p' < credentials.csv |
tr ',' '\012' |
sed -n
  -e '3s/^/aws --profile test configure set aws_access_key_id /p'
  -e '4s/^/aws --profile test configure set aws_secret_access_key /p' |
sh
```

追記: 開発中の [v2に入っている](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/awscli/customizations/configure/importer.py) ようです。 ([クラスメソッドさんの記事](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/user-aws-cli-v2-configure-import/))